# matching a numeric list of vectors to a character list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a list of character strings (vectors) and I have a list of numeric vectors that I want to use to find the words from the first.  I have it arranged as a data table below to help you visualize:

```
                                  words neg2
1 i, do, not, like, when, she, is, mean 2, 8
2               i, think, its, not, bad 1, 4
```

I want to extract the 2nd and 8th word from the character string for row one and then the 1st and fourth words from the character string for row 2 as shown in the MATCH column below:

```
                                 words neg2    MATCH
1 i, do, not, like, when, she, is, mean 2, 8 do, mean
2               i, think, its, not, bad 1, 4   i, not
```

Code to reproduce the 2 lists:

```
neg2<-list(c(2, 8), c(1, 4))
x$words <-list(c("i", "do", "not", "like", "when", "she", "is", "mean"), 
    c("i", "think", "its", "not", "bad"))
```

I know this is easy I'm just not seeing it.  I've tried using match(), with lapply() and various other combinations but am coming up short.

I'd appreciate the most efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized mapply is the answer:

```
SEL<-function(x, y)x[y]
mapply(SEL, x$words, neg2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: `mapply` get's under-used. +1

Comment: If this is the answer, you can flag your own answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
words <- list(c("i", "do", "not", "like", "when", "she", "is", "mean"), 
    c("i", "think", "its", "not", "bad"))
neg2<-list(c(2, 8), c(1, 4))
words[[1]][neg2[[1]]]
words[[2]][neg2[[2]]]
```

Or, for arbitrarily long lists of words and indexes:

```
words1 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(words)) {
    words1[[i]] <- words[[i]][neg2[[i]]]
}
```

Looks like you just need to understand how to index lists in R.  See
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: thanks for the help.  The example is small and indexing makes sense but I'm working with large amounts of text where indexing by 'hand' would not be appropriate.